# sql, group a query with no aggregations and multiple tables

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, group-by, inner-join

I need to group the query below by dda.LA and need to display all the columns listed in the select but almost none of them are aggregated. i don't know what the syntax to get around this is and i can not find a post that shows this syntax (most examples only have one table, two at tops).

```
    Select  dda.a,
    dda.b,
    dda.c,
    dda.d,
    dda.e,
    dda.f,
    dda.g,
    dda.h,
    dda.i,
    dda.j,
    dda.k,
    dda.l,
    dda.m,
    dda.n,
    dda.o,
    dda.p,
    dda.r,
    dda.u,
    dda.LA,
    dd.aa,
    coalesce(apn.apn,Pt.z) as abc,
    coalesce(apn.v,Pt.y) as def,
    'RFN'                       RowFocusIndicator   ,
    'SRI'                       SelectRowIndicator  ,
    'Y'                         Expanded        ,
    Convert(Int, Null)              SortColumn

    From    dda (NoLock)
    Inner Join dd (NoLock) On dda.d = dd.q and dda.e = dd.e
    Left Outer Join apn (nolock) on dda.r = apn.r 
    Left Outer Join Pt (nolock) on dda.s = Pt.t

    Where   1 = 1
        And dda.u =     (Select Min(c.w)
                        From    c (NoLock)
                        Where   c.x = dda.s)
```

Thanks!

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Comment: You will have to mention all the columns in select list to group by saying `group by dda.a,dda.b,dda.c, ...`.

Comment: doing this returns the same number of rows as the select statement without the group..

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to any column that you want to aggregate by:

```
AggregatedColumnName = Aggregation(fieldToAggregate) Over (Partition By dda.LA)
```

ex.

```
aCount = Count(dda.a) Over (Partition By dda.LA)
```